# AngularJS: Creating a class that I can use in my app.js file to use hyperlink pictures

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my app.js file I have classes that are data driven, such as text and picture classes. I have a hyperlink class for which I used Href that looks like this:

```
div class = "links" ng-if="field.fieldLink">
<a ng-if="content.LinkField.fieldLinkNewTab !== false" target="_blank" 
ng-href="{{ content.fieldLink.fieldLinkHref }}">{{ 
content.fieldLink.fieldLinkText }}</a>
<a ng-if="content.fieldLink.fieldLinkNewTab === false" ng-href="{{ 
content.fieldLink.fieldLinkHref }}">{{ 
content.fieldLink.fieldLinkText }} </a>
</div>
```

So this way I can easily use it like this in my .JS file:

```
fieldLink
{
fieldLinkHref: "www.etc.com",
fieldLinkText: "click here for random website",
```

The problem that I am having is making a field for an image:

```
fieldLinkImage: "documents/pictures/etc.jpg"
fieldLinkHref:  "www.etc.com",
```

Clicking the picture should redirect me to the url.

I can do this in my .html file just fine, by simply wrapping the image in the class, but I want to select the image in my .JS file.

How do I make this happen without hard coding the links and images in the .html file ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this but I will criticize your code a bit.
First to point out that you have a typo, `LinkField` should probably be `fieldLink` in your first `<a>` element.

Next, why are you comparing !== false when you can just check if var is true or truthy (just put variable in condition - no need to compare with anything - if it's there or is true it will be truthy).

Also to create a new element just because you need to have different attribute is bad, you will get tons of code and get lost at some point. Instead use `ng-attr-target` which will give you same thing in one line - puts target (or any other) attribute based on condition.

But all of that can be fixed of course, I will take a wild guesses on your data structure during this since you haven't provided jsfiddle or similar. I guess that you have a list of objects that hold images or links and you want to put them together in some ng-repeat based on the type either show link or image.

So this would be your data object:

```
let contentObj = [{
    fieldLink: {
      fieldLinkNewTab: false,
      fieldLinkHref: "www.etc.com",
      fieldLinkText: "click here for random website",
    }
  }, {
    fieldLink: {
      fieldLinkNewTab: true,
      fieldLinkHref: "www.etc.com",
      fieldLinkImage: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/590490/pexels-photo-590490.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb",
    }
  }];
```

and this would be your html, if fieldLinkText is there it will show text, if fieldLinkImage is there it will show image, keep in mind if you have both it will show both, also by utilizing power of ng-attr-target you show one element in html and not two with ng-if:

```
<div class="links" ng-repeat="content in contentObj" ng-if="content.fieldLink">
      <a ng-attr-target="{{(content.fieldLink.fieldLinkNewTab) ? '_blank' : undefined}}" ng-href="{{ content.fieldLink.fieldLinkHref }}">
        <span ng-if="content.fieldLink.fieldLinkText">{{ content.fieldLink.fieldLinkText }}</span>
        <img class="image-class" ng-if="content.fieldLink.fieldLinkImage" src="{{content.fieldLink.fieldLinkImage}}" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
```

I hope this is helpful, I didn't mean to be too critic, if I was sorry about that, but these things will help you in future. And here's the fiddle that you can play on change your data tweak it up a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/j392Lvdp/3/